# Rails update multiple records if each record is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to update record in one, single shot to db when `published_at` is nil instead of two:

```
  portfolio_report.update!(published: true)
  portfolio_report.update!(published_at: DateTime.current) if portfolio_report.published_at.nil?
```

Is it possible to have something like:

```
  portfolio_report.update!(
    published: true,
    published_at: DateTime.current if nil?
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options here actually. Maybe the one that answers your question most directly is:

```
portfolio_report.update!(
  published: true,
  published_at: portfolio_report.published_at || DateTime.current
)
```

(This assumes `published_at` has not been updated from another thread and made this in-memory instance stale, but it matches the behaviour of the original example, so I assume that is not a problem.)

You could also accomplish the same thing with a `before_update` callback, but that would both be more indirect and require more code.

Either way, it's probably a good idea to encapsulate this in a method on your `PortfolioReport` model:

```
class PortfolioReport < ApplicationRecord
  def publish!
    update!(
      published: true,
      published_at: published_at || DateTime.current
    )
  end
end
```

This way every call site does not need to remember to get this right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use where to limit it and make one line.

```
portfolio_report.where(published_at: nil).update!(published_at: DateTime.current, published: true)
```

Comment: Nope, I cannot do this because I will receive an empty array in case where `published_at` is not nil. So I won't be able to update `published` for a record with existing `published_at`.

Comment: Well in that case you have to use two, as you want to search by nil date and update its date. But also want all published to true, so in SQL you can't do that together in one query.

Answer (score 0):

You can add data to record and after save it.

```
portfolio_report.published = true
portfolio_report.published_at = DateTime.current if portfolio_report.published_at.nil?
portfolio_report.save!
```